# What is technical difference (internal voltage) between Digital multimeter's current measuring ranges mA (milliampere) and A(ampere)?

Tags: current-measurement, brownout

- Is there any difference in internal power supply (DMM's) while knob turned to mA and A.
- While measuring current in my microcontroller-module with keeping **mA** on **DMM**, I am getting brownout detected (current loading ?) but not when kept at **A** range given current measured =35mA. Basically if current is in mA range why  keeping knob at mA should produce any errors ?

Comment: "*I am getting brownout detected (current loading ?)*." This sentence is unclear. Hit the edit link under your question to clarify.

Comment: Exactly what is indicating a brownout - something on the DMM or something on...?

Answer (score 3):

Nearly all DMMs are in essence **volt meters**.

What can you do if you only have a volt meter but want to measure a current? You use a **resistor**. In measurement terms we call that a **shunt resistor** and the current you want to measure needs to flow through it.

*What if we want to measure 1 A?*

We could use a 0.1 ohm resistor and then we would measure 0.1 V across that resistor.

*What if we want to measure 10 mA?*

We could use a 10 ohm resistor and then we would measure 0.1 V across that resistor.

So your DMM very likely only uses a **different value** shunt resistor for the mA and A range. Optionally there might be a (different) fuse or no fuse (for 10 A or more range for example) for each range.

The **brownout** you get because of the **supply voltage** becoming too low. If you measure in the mA range the shunt resistor has a higher value compared to measuring in the A range. At startup your product might **for a short time** use a lot of current. That high current across the shunt resistor for the mA range can result in so much voltage drop ([burden voltage](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/how-to-measure-the-burden-voltage-of-your-multimeter/)) that the supply voltage for your microcontroller becomes too low and the **brownout detection** triggers.

**Bonus info:** [Here's an article](https://www.eleccircuit.com/digital-multimeter-circuit-using-icl7107/) describing a typical DMM from the end of the previous century, using an ICL7107 IC. Note how for the current ranges each range uses a different combination of resistors.

Comment: Your 7107 example Ammeter suggests that the high-current range (2A) is reserved to its own jack - a good (but expensive) choice. Sounds like the OP's multimeter routes high-current **through the selector switch** - a bad practice - switch contact resistance increases the meter's burden voltage.